# django: foreign key triggers as many queries as objects returned

Tags: django, django-models

I defined a UserProfile with a OneToOne rel to User.

Basically:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', unique=True)
```

When I query the UserProfile, I am surprised to see a query for each user in addition to the main query.

For example, I have 6 users / userprofiles, in a shell, I do:

```
from django.db import connection
connection.queries = [] # reset

UserProfile.objects.all()
len(connection.queries) # 7 queries
```

Looking at the queries, the first query is on the UserProfile table as expected but then there are 6 queries on the User table, one per user. Is that normal? I thought the FK were queried when accessed...

```
SELECT "test_userprofile"."id", "test_userprofile"."created", "test_userprofile"."modified", "test_userprofile"."time_zone", "test_userprofile"."user_id"
FROM "test_userprofile" LIMIT 21

SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", 
       "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" 
FROM "auth_user" 
WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 1

SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", 
       "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" 
FROM "auth_user" 
WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 2

etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally figured out why it happens like that.
When running directly `UserProfile.objects.all()` in the shell, the result is "printed" and the `__unicode__` method of my UserProfile uses the user `self.user`which triggers the additional requests.